# On the free resolution of module of Kahler differentials of a hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, jacobian, derivations

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Consider the local ring $S=k[x_1,...,x_d]_{(x_1,...,x_d)}$, and call its maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. Let $f\in k[x_1,...,x_d]$ be such that  $f\in \mathfrak m^2\setminus \mathfrak m^3$. Let $R=S/fS$. I believe that the module of Kahler differentials $\Omega_R$ fits into an exact sequence
$R \xrightarrow{\Theta} R^{\oplus d }\to \Omega_R \to 0$, where theta is multiplication by the Jacobian matrix of $f$.

My question is: Is the map $\Theta$ injective?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was a bit confused. But still, if $R$ is an integral domain, then $\Theta$ is injective if and only if it has a non-zero entry. Because if $r \in R$ is in the kernel of $\Theta$, then $r \cdot \Theta_i = 0$ for all $i = 1, \dotsc, d$, where $\Theta_i$ is the $i$-th entry of $\Theta$.

Comment: @red_trumpet: yes if $R$ is an integral domain then certainly $\Theta$ is injective as $f$ is a non-zero non-constant polynomial so one of the partial derivatives of $f$ has to be non-zero. But what if $R$ is not an integral domain?

Comment: Try. $d=1$ and $f=x^2$.